# XCode Project Libraries and Version Control

Tags: objective-c, xcode, version-control

I've just discovered, via the Objective Flickr API, that you can add projects into xcode as secondary libraries for your own project. It's very nifty, and it's finally let me get on top of the Flickr stuff I wanted to do.

Problemo! I need to bung this stuff into version control. Presumably the .proj file is what keeps a record of these references and libraries? Is that what I  need to commit to make sure other people working on this project get the libraries? Additionally, in the past, committing the .proj file has conflicted very badly with other people. Is there a good way of doing it? Should it be done at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the `.xcodeproj` file, then yes, you should commit that to version control. It'll contain all the file references and settings that someone else needs to compile the project.